# Javafx application gives error when minimized in Mac

Tags: macos, javafx, java-7, eclipse-kepler

I build a project just like ODesk Tracker which take snapshots after intervals. The application is working fine in windows and linux. But in Mac when i minimize the application. It gives Error and a popup displays **Java Quit Unexpectedly.**

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff885a20e6, pid=1386, tid=1287
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0-b118) (build 1.8.0-ea-b118)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.0-b60 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x80e6]  objc_release+0x16
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/babita/Documents/workspace/FBTracker 2/hs_err_pid1386.log
```

Comment: Can you give some more details of your problem, or your codes which is causing it.

Comment: I made some changes, Now Fatal Error is not coming but Application goes to System Tray and never Respond.
Just Waiting notifier revolves around application Icon. this.secondaryStage = new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);